# Is there a python equivilent to NDhist in matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, histogram, heatmap, frequency-distribution

[Here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45325-efficient-2d-histogram--no-toolboxes-needed/content/ndhist.m) is the link to the Matlab function, I was wondering if anyone had come across something similar in python. I want to input X and Y arrays of the same length and generate what is essentially a heatmap. Where the frequency of times a coordinate falls in a bin dictates the color of said bin.

Any help is much appreciated or advice on how to do this in a different way!

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply...

If you can use numpy, there is a function for that - `numpy.histogram2d` ( http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html ) to get data.

If you want to see the plot and you can use matplotlib, there is `matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d` (see example: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hist2d_log_demo.html )

And (*disclaimer: I wrote it and want to get some publicity for it ;-)*) you can use the `physt` library. See the examples of 2D histograms here: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/janpipek/physt/blob/master/doc/2D%20Histograms.ipynb